# Ping a website in R

Tags: r, ping

I would like to create a script in R that pings a given website. I haven't found any information about this specific for R.

To start with, all I need is the information on whether the website responses to the ping or not.

Does anyone have information about existing scripts or which package best to use to start with?

Comment: A comment on terminology: pinging is directed to a host, not a website.  If it matters, you may want to understand the difference between a server, host, IP, domain, and website.  It isn't a big deal for most purposes, though.

Comment: Note that some people construe "ping a website" to mean "send a GET query and make sure a response code 200 is returned".  I agree it's not the common terminology but it is out there.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

We can use a `system2` call to get the return status of the ping command in the shell. On Windows (and probably linux) following will work :

```
ping <- function(x, stderr = FALSE, stdout = FALSE, ...){
    pingvec <- system2("ping", x,
                       stderr = FALSE,
                       stdout = FALSE,...)
    if (pingvec == 0) TRUE else FALSE
}

# example
> ping("google.com")
[1] FALSE
> ping("ugent.be")
[1] TRUE
```

If you want to capture the output of ping, you can either set `stdout = ""`, or use a system call:

```
> X <- system("ping ugent.be", intern = TRUE)
> X
 [1] ""                                                         "Pinging ugent.be [157.193.43.50] with 32 bytes of data:" 
 [3] "Reply from 157.193.43.50: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=62"       "Reply from 157.193.43.50: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=62"      
 [5] "Reply from 157.193.43.50: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=62"       "Reply from 157.193.43.50: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=62"      
 [7] ""                                                         "Ping statistics for 157.193.43.50:"                      
 [9] "    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss)," "Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:"          
[11] "    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms"
```

using the option `intern = TRUE` makes it possible to save the output in a vector. I leave it to the reader as an exercise to rearrange this in order to get some decent output.

Comment: Thanks (upvoted) but it's looping. In your code we have to use `ping -c1`  (or a finite number). `system2("ping", paste0("-c1 ",x),`. link: [Ping for 4 times](https://askubuntu.com/a/200992/972235)

Comment: It works on **Mac** too. Its just that when the ping is good (the host is available), the function doesn't immediately return the `TRUE` boolean value. However, when the ping is bad (the host is unavailable), the function immediately returns the `FALSE` boolean value.

Comment: [The suggestion by **phili_b**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7012796/ping-a-website-in-r#comment102774203_7013503) solves the issue I mentioned about the [function not returning immediately the value `TRUE`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7012796/ping-a-website-in-r#comment123118904_7013503).

Answer (score 12):

`RCurl::url.exists` works for localhost (where ping doesn't always) and is faster than `RCurl::getURL`.

```
> library(RCurl)
> url.exists("google.com")
[1] TRUE
> url.exists("localhost:8888")
[1] TRUE
> url.exists("localhost:8012")
[1] FALSE
```

Note that it is possible to set the timeout (which by default is rather long)

```
> url.exists("google.com", timeout = 5) # timeout in seconds
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to see if a website is responding to HTTP requests, you can test an URL in R with the [RCurl library](http://www.omegahat.org/RCurl/), which is an R interface to the [curl HTTP client library](http://curl.haxx.se/).

Example:

```
> library(RCurl);
> getURL("http://www.google.com")
[1] "<!doctype html><ht....
```

If you want to examine the response code (for 200, 404, etc.) you will need to write a custom function to pass as the "header" option to getURL().

Answer (score 3):

To get the status code

```
library(httr)

b <- GET("http://www.google.com")

b$status_code

[1] 200
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a package for this ... {pingr} [Link to CRAN](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/pingr/index.html).

```r
library(pingr)

# check if domain can be reached via port 80
is_up(destination = "example.com")

## [1] TRUE


# check how domain name is resolved to ip adress
nsl("example.com")

## $answer
##          name class type   ttl          data
## 1 example.com     1    1 85619 93.184.216.34
## 
## $flags
## aa tc rd ra ad cd 
## NA NA NA NA NA NA 


# check HTTP port
pingr::ping_port("example.com", 80)


# check HTTPS port
pingr::ping_port("example.com", 443)
```