# Message (alert) if no internet connection in Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

**Scenario:**

I have a Shiny app that saves inputs and sends the data as a file via e-mail (or to One Drive/Dropbox)

If there is no active internet connection, this procedure fails.

**Question:**

Is there a way to alert the user of the Shiny app that there is no internet connection (available at the moment)?

Comment: You can ping the end-point to see if its available https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7012796/ping-a-website-in-r

Comment: Check the `pingr` package. It has a function `is_online`.